# Что не так с размером диска?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, linux-mint, диск

#### Linux Mint 17.1:

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf3d7eaf1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048   524290047   262144000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       524290048  1953521663   714615808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

#### Windows 7:

```
C:\>wmic diskdrive get size,status
Size           Status
1000202273280  OK
1000202273280  OK
```

Такой же размер показывает `msinfo32`.

Почему размеры отличаются на **2612736 байт**?

Comment: возможно, видновс показывает размер диска без учета хвоста для выравнивания. В конце диска часто существует небольшой (пара метров) неиспользуемый кусок. А линукс показал полный размер. Если у него спросить размер раздела, то вполне может ответить таким же уменьшенным размером.

Comment: @KoVadim, что за хвост, можно подробнее? Тут речь не о разделе, а об устройстве. На нём 2 раздела. И ещё, не можешь подсказать, [здесь](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507802/178988) всё верно, или я ещё что-то забыл? Этот самый хвост?

Comment: В случае линукса я уверен, что он скорее всего показывает размер устройства. В случае с виндой - нет.  При разбитии диска утилиты оставляют небольшой хвост в конце, что бы общий размер был кратный 4мб (или 4 кб - все от многого зависит). Так винда более оптимально может использовать диск.

Comment: @KoVadim, 1953521663*512 = 1000203091456 - ни с одним из вариантов не сходится. (Добавил полный вывод fdisk в вопрос). Или что-то другое имеется в виду?

Comment: @KoVadim, если я захочу в virtualbox создать диск такого размера, какой размер мне надо указать?

Comment: большего. Как линукс пишет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37665/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-kovadim).

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, почему ты считаешь, что метки конкретных систем важны в этом вопросе?

Comment: @Qwertiy а вдруг кто нибудь будет искать просто вопросы с ключевым словом mint или windows7 ? :)

Comment: Linux показывает более правильный размер. В Oracle VM VirtualBox лучше поставить "резиновый" диск, увеличивающийся по мере заполнения данными - тогда и таких вопросов возникать не будет.

Comment: @Justicet, но ведь у резинового диска тоже выставляется размер. Просто он в реальной системе его не занимает, если это не требуется. Или там ещё какая-то разновидность резиновых есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не совсем: выставляется начальный минимальный размер. Например, я ставлю 20ГБ под ХР (с учетом того, что установлю туда несколько специфических программ большого объема), при превышении данного размера VBox автоматически увеличит размер "файла-диска"